# Load partial view in a div MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button on my MVC view on click of it, it should add a partial view in a 'div', by calling an action which takes an object as a parameter

I tried out some thing like this:

```
$('#buttonId').onclick(function(){

$('#divid').load(@Html.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new{parameterName = objectToPass}))

});
```

but it loads the actionresult/partial view on page load itself not a click of button

Any Idea?

Comment: You need `Url.Action` to get the Url. `Html.Action` will execute the action and return the view result.

Comment: Same you can't pass an object using URl.Action

Comment: How complex is this object? Can you pass just the id? Otherwise, make ajax call to HttpPost the object as json, then in the response handler you load the html into the div.

Answer (score 23):

Try to use

```
@Url.Action
```

instead of

```
@Html.Action
```

Or you can use ajax, for example:

```
$('#buttonId').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
        data: objectToPass,
        success: function (data) {
           $('#divid').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: To help explain, HTML.Action would generate and returns the HTML of your partial view.  This would be for if you want it to run immediately, and it's use would be different (used directly, not via ajax.)  URL.Action creates a URL string for requesting the partial view.  So if you want the browser to make an ajax call to that would acquire and render the content, you need to use the URL.  Especially if your plan is to delay/defer the call until the browser already has the main page.

Answer (score 10):

Load Partial View in a div MVC 4

Recently I want load Partal View in Div , after doing lots of R&D and It's work for me

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
    data: {
        title: title
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#divid').innerHTML = result;
    }
});
```

And In Partal View Action Controller Code

```
public PartialViewResult ShowCategoryForm(string title)
{
    Model model = new Model();
    model.Title = title;
    return PartialView("~/Views/ControllerName/PartalView.cshtml", model);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buttonId').click(function () {
            $('#divid').load('@Url.Action("About", "Home")');
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="buttonId">Load partial view or Any URL</a>

<div id="divid" style="height:100px; width:400px";>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

load require a string, you are generating a variable path
if you look at your source code it generate something like:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('#divid').load(yoururl/);
});
```

but what you want is:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('#divid').load("yoururl/");
});
```

the code should look like:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('#divid').load('@Html.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new{parameterName = objectToPass})');
});
```

but as I can see the load should be working until you click on `#buttonId`

Comment: How can you pass an object in a URL ?-

Comment: you want to add a string to it, not an object/variable that is a url-path, look at the last example

Comment: In question I am calling an action for partial view, which takes an object as a parameter, and what you are saying is to give Partial view URL instead of calling an action, So how can I pass an object in URL ????

Comment: you can in your codebehind say `if Request.IsAjaxRequest() { return ParitalView.... }`

Answer (score 1):

On ajax call success function append result

ajax call=>

```
url: 'controllername/methodname'
 success: function (partialviewresult)
{ 
          $('#div').append(partialviewresult);
}

  // inside controller
 public ActionResult methodname()
{
    return PartialView("~/a/a.cshtml");
}
```

and controller must return partialview as result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of innerHTML, html(data) worked for me;

```
$('#buttonId').click( function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
    data: objectToPass,
    success: function (data) {
       $('#divid').html(data);
    }
});}
```