# Partial View Not Rendering inside div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So I was trying to follow [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1057064/MVC-Master-Detail-Example-with-Partial-View-and-Mo) and [the followup article.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1046102/MVC-pagination-filtering-and-sorting-inside-partia)

But Before I started with the searching, sorting and filtering, I wanted to see if even the pages were working as intended.

Unfortunately they are not and I cant for the life of me figure it out why, I even went so far as to download his working example just to see if it was something with my browser. (To download his working example its at the top of the second article, I cant post more then 2 links)

Since his worked I compared his views, controllers and scripts side by side to mine and from what I can tell they mirror each other.

So I ended up copying my code somewhere else and pasted his into my project, changed the ActionLinks to reflect the naming conventions I used and left out the stuff I havent implemented yet (noted above). And it still do sent work.

When I run them side by side I get no errors in the console, they are loading the same scripts with the exception that I added jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js as an attempt to correct it from searching for solutions, but it didnt help.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here :/

My Manage View - Correlates to his Home Index View
The only thing I really changed here is the action link

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/ModalDialog.js"></script>
    <style>
        .testClass {
            font-size: xx-large;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
    </style>
    <title>
        Complete example of MVC pagination, filtering and sortig inside patial view with edit in modal dialog

    </title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top:0">

    <table style="width:100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="" colspan="2">

                <div id="logo" style="height:70px; background-color:rgba(86, 111, 111, 1);font: 1.5em Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;">
                    Complete example of MVC pagination, filtering and sortig inside patial view with edit in modal dialog
                </div>
                <div id="navigation" style="background-color:#a4c2c2">
                    <a href="index" class="current">HOME</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:600px">
            <td style="width:200px;background-color: #a4c2c2; vertical-align:top; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>

                            @Html.ActionLink("Manage Assets", "MasterDetail", "Assets", new { }, new { id = "btnCustomers", @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="contentFrame" style="width:100%; height:600px; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache : false})
        $('#btnCustomers').click(function () {
            $('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");
            $('#contentFrame').load(this.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
                $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
            });
            return false;
        });

    });





</script>
```

My MasterDetail View - Correlates to his Customers Index view
My table is setup different because i havent done everything he has yet

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Furst_Alpha_2._0.Models.Quantities>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="~/Scripts/ModalDialog.js"></script>
<h2>Inventory Management</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "_Create", new { id = -1 }, new { btnName = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Make
        </th>
        <th>
            Model
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Length
        </th>
        <th>
            Width
        </th>
        <th>
            Height
        </th>
        <th>
            Weight
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Rental Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Number Of Techs
        </th>
        <th>
            Total
        </th>
        <th>
            In User
        </th>
        <th>
            Availability
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Make.MakeName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Model.ModelName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Type.TypeName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Length)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Width)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Height)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Weight)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.Description)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.RentalPrice)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assets.NumTechsReq)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.total)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InUse)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.QuantityId }, new { btnName = "btnEdit", @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.QuantityId }, new { btnName = "btnDelete", @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    <div id="myPager">

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("MasterDetail", new { page, OrderID = ViewBag.OrderID }))
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        setDialogLink($('a[btnName=btnCreate]'), 'Add New Asset', 500, 600, "contentFrame", "/Assets/MasterDetail");
        setDialogLink($('a[btnName=btnEdit]'), 'Edit Customer', 500, 600, "contentFrame", "/Customers/Index");
        setDialogLink($('a[btnName=btnDetails]'), 'Customer Details', 500, 600, "contentFrame", "/Customers/Index");

        $('a[btnName=btnDelete]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var confirmResult = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (confirmResult)
            {
                $('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: this.href,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify({}),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        traditional: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if (data.success) {
                                $('#contentFrame').load("/Customers/Index");
                            }
                            else {

                                alert(data.errormessage);
                            }
                            $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("An error has occured!!!");
                            $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
                        }

                    });
            }

        })


        $("a[btnName=FilterCustomer]").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var search = $('input[name=search]').val();
            this.href = this.href.replace('xyz', search);
            $('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
                    $('#contentFrame').html(result);
                }

            });
        });


        $(".SortButton").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
                    $('#contentFrame').html(result);
                }

            })

        });


        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
                    $('#contentFrame').html(result);

                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

My AssetsController Manage and MasterDetail methods which correlate to his HomeController Index and CustomerController Index methods respectively.

```
// GET: Assets
        public ActionResult Manage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: MasterDetail
        public ActionResult MasterDetail(int? page)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            //ApplicationUser user = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == userr.Id);

            var assets = db.Quantities.Where(a => a.VendorId == user.VendorId).OrderByDescending(a => a.AssetId);
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 3;
            return PartialView(assets.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So last night while laying in bed stumped as to whats causing the problem I thought well maybe I should just look up alternatives. I saw some Ajax variations (that youll see commented out) and I ended up on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788654/load-partial-view-in-a-div-mvc) which ultimately lead me to a solution.

Below is the end result of my tinkering, I left commented code in from my attempts so you'll see other thigns I've tried. Other than this all I changed in the view was add a reference for a [modal wait screen](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/jQuery-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Loading-Modal-With-Progress-Bar-waitingFor.html) and then changed Html.ActionLink to a button. `<input id="btnCustomers" type="button" value="Manage Assets" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache : false})
        $('#btnCustomers').click(function () {
            //$('#contentFrame').mask("waiting ...");
            waitingDialog.show("Please wait while we prepare your inventory ...");
            $('#contentFrame').load('@Url.Action("MasterDetail","Assets")', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    waitingDialog.hide();
                }, 1000);
            });

            //$.ajax({
            //    type: 'GET',
            //    url: '@Url.Content("~/Assets/MasterDetail")',
            //    data: -1,
            //    success: function (data) {
            //       $('#contentFrame').innerHtml = waitingDialog.hide();
                    //$('#contentFrame').load('@Url.Action("MasterDetail","Assets")');
            //    }
            //})
            //$('#contentFrame').load(this.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
            //    $('#contentFrame').unmask("waiting ...");
            //});
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about what your problem is, but I THINK there I saw a problem in your code.

in `MasterDetail.cshtml` try replacing

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("_MasterDetail", new { page, OrderID = ViewBag.OrderID }))
```

with

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("MasterDetail", new { page, OrderID = ViewBag.OrderID }))
```

`Url.Action` expects an Action name, not a razor view name.

Comment: Ah I missed that because I use to have my PartialViews begin with an "_" it was just left over. The first problem that Im trying to solver is the   `@Html.ActionLink("Manage Assets", "MasterDetail", "Assets", new { }, new { id = "btnCustomers", @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })` from Manage View, was not getting rendering MasterDetail inside the div.

Comment: hmmm ok. Have you fixed the problem ? I'm going to keep looking into it :-)